# Find CSS styles assigned to an element

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

***Get the rendered style of an element***
(Should be able to handle inline CSS also)

I have been learning [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and understand how to select a node based on an ID or Class.  However, I would like to select a node/element and get back the specific CSS styles assigned to it, including inherited styles.

CSS Style Sheet:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .myfont {font-family: Times New Roman: font-size: 80% }
    .bold {font-weight: bold}
    .50_font_size { font-size:50% }
   </style>
 </head>
```

HTML:

```
<Body>
   <div id="article1" class="myfont">
      <div id="title1" class="bold">  
          My Title Text
          <div id="author1" class="50_font_size">
             By First Name Last Name
          </div>
      </div>
        General article text. General article text. General article text.        
      </div>
   </div>
```

In the above example, I would like to use...

```
require "nokogiri"
document=Nokogiri.HTML(HTML_String)

#Hoping for something like the following:
author_css = node.css_style("author1") 
puts author_css
#=>  {font-family=>"Times New Roman",
#=>   font-weight=> "bold",
#=>   font-size=> 50%}
```

As you can see it should output the inherited items, so that I get the correct CSS of the element.  What is the best way to get this result?

Comment: You may want to investigate browser drivers like watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with Nokogiri by itself. Using [CSS_Parser](https://github.com/alexdunae/css_parser) will supply the missing piece:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'css_parser'
include CssParser

html = <<END_HTML
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .myfont {font-family: Times New Roman: font-size: 80% }
    .bold {font-weight: bold}
    .50_font_size { font-size:50% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="article1" class="myfont">
      <div id="title1" class="bold">  
          My Title Text
          <div id="author1" class="50_font_size">
            By First Name Last Name
          </div>
      </div>
        General article text. General article text. General article text.        
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
END_HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
css = doc.at('style').text

parser = CssParser::Parser.new
parser.add_block!(css)

author_div = doc.at('div#author1')
puts parser.find_by_selector('.' + author_div['class'])
```

Which outputs:

```
font-size: 50%;
```

To get the inherited CSS you'll need to start at the top of the document and drill down to your desired node, figuring out what parent node's settings will affect your target node.

Comment: good info - didn't know about CSSParser til now. shame on me. thanks!

Comment: Was hoping for a similar function to javascript's getcomputedstyle().   Trying to avoid writing a script to traverse the nodes since I also need inline CSS and parsing inline CSS can get tricky.  I was also considering using Watir.

Comment: Watir might do it. For what you're doing, you need to know everything the browser knows, which is a different domain/problem than what a language like Ruby, Python or Perl knows on its own.

Comment: Using Watir or phantomjs, you run the getcomputedstyle() function directly (e.g. `watir_browser.execute_script("window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('author1'))")`)